# Play/pause button on keyboard vs. play/pause on BT headphones

Tags: audio, keyboard, bluetooth, media-keys

I have an HP Pavilion laptop running Windows 11, which has media keys on the function keys. I have a Logitech mouse with a button mapped to play/pause, and I also have a pair Sony Bluetooth headphones with media controls on it.

The play/pause button the headphones seems to control something different from the others!  I have iTunes open, and I have a video open in Chrome. Both the play/pause on my keyboard and mouse controls iTunes, and the play/pause on my headphones controls the Chrome video.

If I close iTunes, now all play/pause buttons control the Chrome video.  When I re-open iTunes it's back to the old behavior where keyboard and mouse play/pause controls iTunes and the headphones control Chrome videos.

Why are they different? How can I change this behavior? I have no special key remapping software installed.  The BT headphones seems to be the outlier here and I've just connected that normally in Windows.

Comment: You could check what kind of keycode is sent to the system with AHK or any other similar app, then remap it if needed.

Comment: That's a good idea, I made on using JS here: https://codepen.io/chrismbarr/pen/VwEKNeK - unfortunately all three buttons return the same keycode `179` with the name `MediaPlayPause`

Comment: Hmm, that's weird then, not sure if anything can be done in that case. Is it consistent? As a hardcore user of BT headsets, I can say they are surely very clunky on Windows. I haven't experienced that exact issue, but I've had issues with programs not recognizing media controls at all sometimes or controlling YT Music even though it was clearly not the last app, which is similar to your issue, but not quite. Usually what helps is going to BT settings -> clicking "disconnect" on the headset, turning BT off, turning headset off and then turning BT and headset back on again. Try, maybe it'll help

Comment: Then it gets more stable for a while. These are the problems of my current headset (Momentum M2), I had 2 other ones earlier and the both had different inconsistent issues appearing every now and then. I think there's something wrong in terms how Windows handles the communication, as I didn't have similar issues on Android/Linux.